# How to get the running of time of my program with gettimeofday()

Tags: c, time, type-conversion

So I get the time at the beginning of the code, run it, and then get the time.

```
struct timeval begin, end;
gettimeofday(&begin, NULL);

//code to time

gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
//get the total number of ms that the code took:
unsigned int t = end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec;
```

Now I want to print it out in the form "**code took 0.007 seconds to run" or something similar.

So two problems:

1) t seems to contain a value of the order 6000, and I KNOW the code didn't take 6 seconds to run.

2) How can I convert t to a double, given that it's an unsigned int?  Or is there an easier way to print the output the way I wanted to?

Comment: Well I guess mistaking milli and micro is better than spending 3 hours wondering why my server wasn't running in java.  Turns out I missed the static modifier in the main method.

Comment: If you are using gettimeofday, don't forget to include tv_sec in your calculation (see SoapBox's answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) That's because `usec` is not 6000 milliseconds, it's 6000 microseconds (6 milliseconds or 6 one-thousandths of a second).

2) Try this: `(double)t / 1000000` That will convert t to a double, and then divide it by one million to find the number of seconds instead of the number of microseconds.

Answer (score 17):

`timeval` contains two fields, the seconds part and the microseconds part.

`tv_usec` (*u* meaning the greek letter *mu*, which stands for micro) is the microseconds.  Thus when you get 6000, that's 6000 microseconds elapsed.
`tv_sec` contains the seconds part.

To get the value you want as a double use this code:

```
double elapsed = (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) + 
              ((end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec)/1000000.0);
```

Make sure you include the `tv_sec` part in your calculations.  `gettimeofday` returns the current time, so when the seconds increments the microsecond will go back to 0, if this happens while your code is running and you don't use `tv_sec` in your calculation, you will get a negative number.

Comment: +1: thanks for clarifying the microsecond reset to zero... was exactly where I got stuck...